# How to create a plugin in moodle

Tags: moodle

How to create a plugin in moodle 2.0? I want to create a plugin , like if I enabled from plugins, that has to be enabled on the back/front end.

I was trying to see the file structure for how to create a plugin in moodle 2.0. Please help on that part I need the url or steps to create a plugin on moodle 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

The official site contains some basic documentation. Look at this page: http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Developer_documentation#Make_a_new_plugin

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a plugin in Moodle, a good idea can be to download a module template. Basically it is a simple plugin you can modify for your needs. 
For more details you can see [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/NEWMODULE_Documentation). Please, note that the page is a work in progress, but I found it very useful for starting creating my plugins.
There is also a tutorial you may want to read (see [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/NEWMODULE_Tutorial)), containing other complementary useful information.

Be aware that there are different types of plugins in Moodle (see [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Plugin_types)), having slightly different structures, and you should roughly know what type of plugin you are going to develop before starting developing.

Finally, if you want to see what are the *common structures* shared among plugins, you may want to give a look [here](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Plugin_files).